# Generating a Table with a certain Density

Tags: list-manipulation, random

How do I create a random table of 0's and 1's with a certain density instead of a probability?

For Example:

```
Manipulate[Table[RandomChoice[{1 - density, density} -> {0, 1}, {10}]],
 {density, 0, 1, .01}]
```

There is not always a 50% density of 0's to 1's.

Comment: RandomSample[Join[ConstantArray[0, 5], ConstantArray[1, 5]]]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard♦ Was this asked before? Where? I'd like to be able to look at the answers.

Comment: @Schwarz Click the link above for "Specifying an array..."

Comment: @Schwarz As Michael said, the link to the original is inserted in the gray box above your question.  You are *not* the first to ask that either.  Do you have a suggestion for how that might be made more evident? (A matter of the design of Stack Exchange sites.)